# How to remove pop-up coming when holding button which has image inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have one button with image inside it. When I opening in the mobile device and holding a button, download image pop-up is coming.

How can I hide that pop-up?

```
<button><img src={test_image} width="100%" /></button>
```

its showing me below pop-up
[image: pop-up image]

Comment: put `pointer-events: none;` on the image

Comment: @Ramesh By giving a background image to the button problem is solved as suggested in the link given by you.

Comment: @NishantKhandelwal It doesn't work for this one: ![Just why?](https://replit.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=1080,quality=80/https://storage.googleapis.com/replit/images/1646130858584_1d25428c7bad8e794927b2b9d5636d8b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `-webkit-touch-callout` will help you disable that behavior.

```
img {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Comment: showing "Invalid property value"

Comment: check more detail on here it will work only in iOS Safari == https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout